# Web page only displaying after server stopped

Tags: sockets, erlang, webserver

I am writing a home-made web server in Erlang for learning purposes. The current implementation can parse a HTTP GET request and respond accordingly. The problem is that my test HTML file does not show in the web browser until I shut down the server process. I see the message being sent by prints in the console, but the web browser keeps loading until the server is stopped. The same instant the server is stopped the page is shown. Why is this?

```
listener(Listen) ->
  case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of
    {ok, Client} ->
      case gen_tcp:recv(Client, 0) of
        {ok, Request} ->
          workers:worker({Client, Request});
        {error, closed} ->
          io:format("Socket closed.~n");
        {error, _Reason} ->
          io:format("Error: ~w~n", [_Reason])
      end,
      listener(Listen);
    {error, Error} ->
      io:format("Error ~w~n", [Error]),
      error
  end.

worker({Client, Request}) ->
  {Request_line, Headers, Body} = http_parse:parse_request(Request),
  Response = http_parse:create_response({Request_line, Headers, Body}),
  case gen_tcp:send(Client, Response) of
     ok ->
      io:format("Message sent!~n");
    {error, Reason} ->
      io:format("Could not send packet: ~w~n", [Reason])
  end.
```

Above is some of the code I've written. I've left the parsing out, but that part works. listener/1 receives a socket created by calling gen_tcp:listen/2 with the options list, {active, false}. Any guidance as of why the page displays only after the server is shut down is appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, but your server must be blocking somewhere that you're expecting execution to continue, and doesn't finish executing that stack until you stop the server.

Comment: That might be the case, I'm just clueless about where to start looking. Everything seems to be working fine and I get the "Message sent!" printout. Does the message get stuck in the socket after that?

Comment: Also another thought, the response the server sends out does not currently use any headers. There is only the request line and then the body. Could this cause the page to not show?

Comment: Possibly, but I wouldn't expect the behaviour you described if that were the case. To be honest I don't know enough about erlang to help a whole lot on this, other than to suggest you debug the server and see if it is sitting on something that is blocking further execution.

Comment: What does the actual HTTP response data look like on the wire? Maybe the response is incomplete/malformed and the web browser doesn't know when the response is actually finished, so it has no choice but to go off of the socket closure.

Comment: Also, Erlang has an [HTTP server implementation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html).

Comment: The response contains a request line (HTTP/1.1 200 OK), a blank line and a message body with the requested data. There are no headers (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the response header is missing the `Content-Length` data.

Without a `Content-Length` data, the client assumes that disconnection will mark the end of the data (body) segment.

Your server never closes the connection (nor does it implement a timeout), so the client is kept waiting for more data (it assumes more data is on it's way).

Once the connection is closed, the client marks this as the end of the body (data) segment.

You should consider implementing a timeout as well as managing the response headers for `Content-Length`, `Connection` and `Keep-Alive`.

Consider learning more about the protocol by reading some of the [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) or reading in Wikipedia about the [HTTP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and it's [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).